# Connecting Excel 2010 to SQL Server: Pulling multiple tables from one connection

Tags: sql-server, excel

I want to connect an excel file to several tables in SQL Server. I learned how to make the connection by going to

Data - > Get External Data -> From Other Sources - > From SQL Server

and inputting the server name and selecting a table.

I want to select about 10 more tables. Is there a way to select another table since I  have already set up the connection? Or do I have to go through this whole process each time?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the best way to do this is to use an Excel Add-In called Powerpivot: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg413497(v=sql.110).aspx

It has a data import feature where you can import multiple tables at once from MS SQL Server (and actually supports import for many other database and file types).